# PHP: A simple data structure for dictionary with 3 values/keys

Tags: php, dictionary, data-structures

I have a list of triangles each traingle has an id, perimeter and area.

I need to implement functions to find triangle in the list based on one of the parameters (id or perimeter or area).

The question is how to store the list in this case? I am looking for something simple, which will make these functions small.

I tried to use

```
$triangleList[$id] = [$area,$perimeter];
```

for each triangle to build assoc. array. But now a can't easily find the triangle based on area or perimeter (must use foreach, in_array is not enough).

Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: It's difficult to understand your english when you say "must use foreach, in_array is not enough" so you mean that you do not want to use foreach AND in_array?

Comment: I don't think so. Area and perimeter will not be unique, which is why you won't be able to use them as keys.

Comment: yes, i dont want to use foreach. looking for existing function like in_array

Comment: i need to search by area and perimeter... they are integers for this purpose

Comment: Are the area and perimeter unique for each element in your list?

Answer (score 1):

Say you are looking for triangle with area=2 for example,

```
$subset = array_reduce($triangleList, function ($carry, $item) {
    if ($item['area'] == 2) {
        $carry[] = $item;
    }
}, array());
```

Comment: Intresting... but the complexity for the search function remain the same as with simple solution with foreach. Do you have any suggestions for using other data structure ?

Answer (score 1):

My solution, using three simple arrays in a class. Then using `array_search` for searching functions:

```
class ListOfTriangles {

private $ids = [];
private $areas = [];
private $perimeters = [];

public function addTriangle($id,$area,$perimeter){
    $ids[] = $id;
    $areas[] = $area;
    $perimeters[] = $perimeter;
}

public function getTriangle($index){
    return [$this->ids[$index],$this->areas[$index],$this->perimeters[$index]];
}

public function searchById($id){
    $index = array_search($id, $this->ids);
    return $this->getTriangle($index);
}

public function searchByArea($area){
    $index = array_search($area, $this->areas);
    return $this->getTriangle($index);
}

public function searchByPerimiter($perimiter){
    $index = array_search($perimiter, $this->perimiters);
    return $this->getTriangle($index);
}
}
```